# Jaxb ClassCastException with anonymous inner type in xml and custom bindings

Tags: xml, binding, xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="description"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and the following bindings.xjb

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">    <jxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <xjc:simple/>
</jxb:globalBindings>
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="model.xsd">
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:package name="test"/>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='shiporder']">
        <jxb:class name="Shiporderrrr"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

```
    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='shiporder']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='item']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='item']">
        <jxb:class name="ShiporderItemItem"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='item']">
        <jxb:class name="Item"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='item']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='item']">
        <jxb:class name="ItemItem"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I have the following xml file as well:

```
<shiporder>
  <item>
    <title>string1</title>
     <item>
      <note>string1</note>
     </item>
    </item>
</shiporder>
```

When I unmarshall using jaxb generated classes:

```
import test.Shiporderrrr;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class JaxbTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Shiporderrrr.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Shiporderrrr shiporder = (Shiporderrrr)unmarshaller.unmarshal(Paths.get("src/main/resources/model1.xml").toFile());
        System.out.println(shiporder.getItems().get(0).getValue().getTitle());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:   test.ShiporderItem$ShiporderItemItem cannot be cast to test.ShiporderItem
>       at JaxbTest.main(JaxbTest.java:16)

Could you help me please to find out what I do wrong here?
I think that everything here should work fine.
Should I rewrite my bindings in some other way?

Comment: It might help to provide the extra info that would allow someone to reproduce your problem.   The key things missing are the complete .xsd file (yours doesn't include the root `<schema>` element) and the exact command you use to generate the JAXB classes using the bindings file (e.g. using XJC).  I tried to guess but my attempt failed in the XJC generate step.   Also you might clean up your .xjb file.. it's broken into two parts the way you pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the wrong bindings **/xs:complexType** was missing at the end. Bindings for the nested types should look like below:

```
<jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='item']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='item']/xs:complexType">
    <jxb:class name="ItemItem"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

and then there is no ClassCastException.